# Script for accessing a webpage through a switch won't work?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a script on PowerShell where It asks me if I want to access a list of 3 websites and then ask what browser I would like to use, whether it be Google Chrome or IE.

I know the script that I will be using, which is

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe","http://www.google.com")
```

and `iexplore.exe` for the IE part. But it just ends up giving me an error saying the index is missing and there was an unexpected token. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a part of my code:

```
#Now I added menu 2 to the script by using a switch
Switch ($xMenu1){    #Second Menu appears
    1 {
        while ( $xMenu2 -lt 1 -or $xMenu2 -gt 4 ){
            CLS
            # Menu option appears
            Write-Host "`t Select the browser you would like to open this website with" -Fore Cyan
            Write-Host "`t 1. Google Chrome" -Fore Cyan
            Write-Host "`t 2. IE" -Fore Cyan
            Write-Host "`t 3. Go to Main Menu" -Fore Cyan
            [int]$xMenu2 = Read-Host "`t`tEnter Menu Option Number"
            #The start-Sleep indicates how long the error message starts and disappears 
            if( $xMenu2 -lt 1 -or $xMenu2 -gt 4 ){
                Write-Host "'t error, the number you entered was not part of the menu" -Fore Red;start-Sleep -Seconds 3
            }
        }
        Switch ($xMenu2){
            1{  ""[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe","http://www.google.com")"" }
            2{  "[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("iexplore.exe","http://www.google.com")" }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quoting is messed up here:

```
Switch ($xMenu2){
    1{  ""[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe","http://www.google.com")"" }
    2{  "[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("iexplore.exe","http://www.google.com")" }
}
```

You're trying to call a static method of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class, so you must not put the expression in quotes in the first place:

```
Switch ($xMenu2){
    1{  [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe","http://www.google.com") }
    2{  [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("iexplore.exe","http://www.google.com") }
}
```

Also, if for some reason you must use nested double quotes in a string you must either escape them (`` "...`"..." ``) or use single quotes as the outer quotes (`'..."...'`).